# Check if a ASP.Net website is set to debug configuration

Tags: asp.net

Been given a list of corporate sites from a pen tester that had identified they were published in debug mode. I'm looking to confirm debug mode was changed to release mode, but don't have access to the prod server.

Can I simply attempt to access a non-existing page to confirm if debug mode is on or off? I presume that if I am in debug mode, I'll get the "Server Error in '/' Application", and if I'm in release mode I'll get redirected to the error page>

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: nope, hitting IIS generated 404 page or Server Error Page doesn't mean Debug enabled or disabled. It just means there is no custom error page.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC? In this case and if Bundles are used you'll be able to check if the JavaScript / CSS assets have been bundled and minified.

Comment: ASP.Net 2.0 I'm afraid...

Comment: You're going to have to get with someone that has access to the server